# Adding icon on navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am already done in doing the navigation drawer but i want to add icons beside the title of the navigation list but i dont know how. I already searched many tutorials but they are different to my code. My navigation drawer is my own creation not the drawer activity of android studio thats why i have hard time to find answers on how to add icons. this is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String mActivityTitle;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    EditText license;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();
        license = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loglicense);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        addDrawerItems();
        setupDrawer();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    private void addDrawerItems() {
        String[] Array = { "Driver Details", "List of Drivers", "Maps and Route", "Report Driver", "Contacts", "Display Contacts", "Post on Twitter", "Call For Emergency", "Rate Taxi", "Driver's Feedback", "User's Favorites", "Top Drivers", "Top Operators", "Account Settings" };
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Array);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), DriverDetails.class));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), DriversList.class));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MapsActivity.class));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ReportActivity.class));
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Contacts.class));
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), DisplayContact.class));
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity2Activity.class));
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), EmergencyAssistance.class));
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Rating.class));
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ListComments.class));
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ListFavorite.class));
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), TopDriver.class));
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), TopCompany.class));
                        break;
                    case 13:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ChangePassword.class));
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupDrawer() {
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("TaxiSafe");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), EmergencyAssistance.class));
            return true;
        }

        // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my XML.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- The first child in the layout is for the main Activity UI-->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundlahat"
    android:focusable="false">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Side navigation drawer UI -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navList"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="#ffeeeeee" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You had better use `NavigationView` and set icons using menu.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having simple array adapter, You can have a custom ArrayAdapter which has ImageView and TextView next to it.

There are lot of tutorials on how to write custom ArrayAdapter.

example:

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter

Comment: this tutorial is for listview not in navigation bar.

Comment: private ListView mDrawerList;  isn't it this list view which is actually rendering your navigation drawer items.

Answer (score 0):

This example is simple, check:  [EXAMPLE](http://codetheory.in/android-navigation-drawer/)